# How do I specify the generic parameter from a typeof?

Tags: typescript, native-base

I'm trying to extend NativeBase's FlatList to add a couple more properties.  Since they didn't export the prop type for their FlatList I was thinking of using `Parameters<typeof NBFlatList>[0]` to get their props which is internally `InterfaceFlatListProps<ItemT = unknown>`

What I want to do is pass the type into it.  But I can't seem to pass it in as it loses it's genericity

```js
type NBFlatListProps<ItemT> = Parameters<typeof NBFlatList>[0];
export type FlatListProps<ItemT> = NBFlatListProps & {
  /**
   * number of columns.  Defaults to 1.
   */
  numColumns?: BreakpointValues<number>;
  /**
   * Space between elements
   */
  space?: BreakpointValues<string | number>;
};
```

The `FlatList` declaration (which I changed for this example):

```
export declare const NBFlatList: <ItemT>(props: import("./types").InterfaceFlatListProps<ItemT>, ref: any) => any;
```

Comment: Parameters extends NBFlatList

Comment: TypeScript 4.7 will introduce *instantiation expressions*, as implemented in [ms/TS#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607). At that point you can write what you're doing like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp96xW). If that meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Dude... did TS get upgeraded now? :D
This is like a clean way to do Index Properties!

Comment: I added the NBFlatList declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
//index properties are when you know the type of data you will be receiving but you don't know the name of the property
//you can use Index Properties to access the properties of an array
//here we say we are going to receive data that will have a value which is a string

interface ErrorContainer {
  [prop: string]: string;
}
```

Look at Index Properties in TypeScript
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question; could you explain how it applies?

Comment: It does not appear to either.